# Error in S3 while running user data via terraform

Tags: amazon-s3, timeout, terraform

I am trying to copy a file from S3 using terraform user data. All other command are running but it is unable to copy from S3. While creating a fresh role and policy from console it works fine with same permission.

```
fatal error: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='s3.amazonaws.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /somebucket/index.html (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<botocore.awsrequest.AWSHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fac02dfe550>, 'Connection to s3.amazonaws.com timed out. (connect timeout=60)'))
```

My code is as follows :-

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "CF2TF-IAM-Role" {
  name = "CF2TF-IAM-Role"
  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "CF2TF-IAM-Policy" {
  name = "CF2TF-IAM-Policy"
  policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*"
     }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "CF2TF-IAM-PA" {
  depends_on = ["aws_iam_role.CF2TF-IAM-Role", "aws_iam_policy.CF2TF-IAM-Policy"]
  role = "${aws_iam_role.CF2TF-IAM-Role.name}"
  policy_arn = "${aws_iam_policy.CF2TF-IAM-Policy.arn}"
}

resource "aws_iam_instance_profile" "CF2TF-IAM-IP" {
  name = "CF2TF-IAM-IP"
  depends_on = ["aws_iam_role.CF2TF-IAM-Role"]
  role = "${aws_iam_role.CF2TF-IAM-Role.id}"
}
```

The user data file is as below :-

```
#!/bin/bash
yum update -y
yum install httpd -y
aws s3 cp s3://somebucket/index.html /var/www/html/index.html
service httpd start
```

Comment: Does your instance have the ability to resolve and connect to S3? What does running `telnet s3.amazonaws.com 443` on the instance show?

Comment: No..It cant reach s3.amazonaws.com !!! How come ?

Comment: Did it at least resolve it? What does `nslookup s3.amazonaws.com` show? This is going to be a networking thing on the instance. How is DNS configured for the instance? What does the security group look like on the instance etc?

Comment: Just added all traffic inbound/outbound of Security Group and now it can communicate with S3. Really weird - The SG was running with 443, 22 and ephemeral port only. Now I have added security in NACL to allow in SG.